# Caml query when Title field contains Plus (+) sign

Tags: sharepoint-server, caml-query

This CAML query is not working if `Title` field contains Plus (+) Sign.

My query is :

```
function createSACQuery(Title) {
        var qry = new SP.CamlQuery();
        qry.set_viewXml('<View Scope="RecursiveAll"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text"><![CDATA[' + Title + ']]></Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>');
        return qry;
    }
```

My `Title` is `Lorem Ipsum +`

Comment: Have you tried character escaping such as encodeURI?

Comment: Yes i tried but it is also not working infact after using encodeURI i am getting no result which i am getting from my above query.

Comment: I also tried encodeURIComponent also but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I was fetching value of title from querystring so it automatically removes the Plus(+) sign.

So I created the url like this `www.abcd.com/default.aspx?Title=encodeURIComponent(mytitle)`

It is working fine now.